# Optimal number of URLs in sitemaps URLset

Tags: xml, url, seo, sitemap

I’m trying to find the best approach to create my sitemap (I deal with a huge number of URLs).

I have an XML Sitemap with a tree-structure, it’s composed of many sitemap.xml. Actually I have max 1000 URLs for each sitemap.xml.

What's the optimal number of urls for each sitemap.xml? Does Google prefers a larger number of URLs (greater than 1000), or less URLs distributed in more XML files?

Answer (score 1):

From the [sitemaps.org protocol specification](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html#index):

You can include up to **50,000 URLs** in each Sitemap file:

> […] each Sitemap file that you provide must have no more than 50,000 URLs and must be no larger than 50MB (52,428,800 bytes)
>
> […]
>
> If you want to list more than 50,000 URLs, you must create multiple Sitemap files.

You can link up to **50,000 Sitemap files** in each Sitemap index file:

> Sitemap index files may not list more than 50,000 Sitemaps and must be no larger than 10MB (10,485,760 bytes) […]

You can have multiple Sitemap index files (no limit stated):

> You can have more than one Sitemap index file.

Comment: I don't think that answers the question. 50k urls is the maximum per sitemap file. The question is whether Google has a preference when it comes to sitemap file size. For example it could be possible that Google fetches smaller sitemaps (less than 10k urls) more often than bigger sitemaps because it's less burdensome for the crawler.

Comment: So is there any preference?