# Can i use <sitemap> in <urlset>?

Tags: xml, indexing, seo, xml-sitemap

As the title can i use `<sitemap>` tag in `<urlset>` to point to my second sitemap?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">

  <url>
    <loc>http://website.com/page1</loc>
    <changefreq>hourly</changefreq>
  </url>

  <url>
    <loc>http://website.com/page2</loc>
    <changefreq>hourly</changefreq>
  </url>

  <sitemap>
    <loc>http://website.com/sitemap.xml?offset=1000</loc>
    <changefreq>always</changefreq>
  </sitemap>

</urlset>
```

or must i use `<url>` to point to my second sitemap:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">

  <url>
    <loc>http://website.com/page1</loc>
    <changefreq>hourly</changefreq>
  </url>

  <url>
    <loc>http://website.com/page2</loc>
    <changefreq>hourly</changefreq>
  </url>

  <url>
    <loc>http://website.com/sitemap.xml?offset=1000</loc>
    <changefreq>always</changefreq>
  </url>

</urlset>
```

I cannot use `<sitemapindex>` as i have too many pages to generate a total index file.

Comment: About why you can’t use a Sitemap index file: I’m not sure I understand your reason. If it’s possible for you to add the sitemap URLs under `urlset` of one file, it should also be possible to add these URLs in a different file under `sitemapindex`, no? Each Sitemap index file can have 50000 sitemap URLs, and you can even provide multiple index files ([see limits](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35227004/1591669)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [Sitemap protocol](https://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html) describes, you should use a [Sitemap index file](https://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html#index).

If you add a `sitemap` element as child of the `urlset` element (your first example), it will likely be ignored, as `sitemap` is not one of the [expected elements](https://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html#xmlTagDefinitions).

If you add the sitemap as `url` element inside `urlset` (your second example), your sitemap file is just another URL entry in your sitemap. You shouldn’t expect that consumers handle this entry as another sitemap, as this is not a defined behaviour, but specific consumers might do this anyway, of course.

If you can’t provide a Sitemap index file, you could (as a better-than-nothing alternative) provide multiple `Sitemap` records [in your robots.txt](https://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html#submit_robots):

```
User-agent: *
Disallow:

Sitemap: https://example.com/sitemap.xml?offset=2000

Sitemap: https://example.com/sitemap.xml?offset=1000

Sitemap: https://example.com/sitemap.xml
```